# Expo-Managed App With No Needed Permissions Crashing in Testflight but not Expo Go nor Simulators

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, testflight

I am working on an expo-managed react native app that uses firebase to authenticate users and react-navigation to manage navigation. The app compiles and runs fine in both Expo Go and using EAS Build, however when I upload it to testflight I get an "EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)" error immediately on launch of the app. Former solutions to this problem were based on permissions, but I don't ask nor need any special permissions from the user, so that doesn't help in my case. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been trying to debug this for the past week!

Here are the relevant parts of the testflight crash logs (I have removed the app name with TestApp):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  2

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1c29f1d78 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1db656734 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   TestApp                             0x104c89e7c RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:146)
3   TestApp                             0x104d08f38 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:] + 488 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:68)
4   TestApp                             0x104d09818 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1408 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:135)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1c297a614 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1c2998100 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1c29cf13c -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3475)
8   TestApp                             0x104cbca48 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   TestApp                             0x104cbf03c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 540 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
10  TestApp                             0x104cbec6c operator() + 68 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
11  TestApp                             0x104cbec6c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 112 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c2656e68 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c2658a2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c2660124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c2660c80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1c266b500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23394e0bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x23394de5c start_wqthread + 8
```

Here is what the relevant portions of my App.js looks like:

```
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const auth = getAuth(); 
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            setUser(true);
        } else {
            setUser(false);
        }
        setLoading(false);
     });    
if(loading){
return(<AppLoading />)
}

return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
                {user ? (
                    <MainApp />
                ) : (
                    <Onboarding />
                )}
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
```

Any my dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-spring/native": "^9.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-fast-image": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~0.8.1 || ~0.9.0",
    "expo-react-native-fast-image": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-progressive-graceful-image": "^0.6.14",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Again, any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance for any help!

Edit: Here is a list of things that I have tried

1. Uninstalling, reinstalling, and validating different versions of Expo and React Native
2. Removing all auth hooks from firebase
3. Refactoring the auth flow
4. Moving the initialize firebase key from outside to inside the app.js export

Comment: `expo-file-system` should require  device storage access permission outside of  Expo Go.

Comment: I attempted to remove expo-file-system as a dependency, but that has unfortunately not resolved the error :(